# Will my personal google play development account being terminated affect the customer's google play

Tags: android

I have a banned personal google play developer account (mail A), this account I have logged in on my company computer and on that computer I have a corporate mail account (mail B). I am worried that new projects using firebase or new google play developer account will be affected when my client invites my corporate mail account (mail B)?
Thanks for your support.

I've tried looking into account terminated cases but haven't found any firebase or Google Console invites yet